# Merge tuple of objects into one object type

Tags: typescript, object, spread-syntax

This function **must** support any number of arguments:

```
type Result<T extends object[]> = "???"

function merge<T extends object[]>(...sources: T): Result<T> {
  return Object.assign({}, ...sources)
}
```

Example input with expected result type: [(playground)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Result%3CT%20extends%20object%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%22%3F%3F%3F%22%0A%0Afunction%20merge%3CT%20extends%20object%5B%5D%3E(...sources%3A%20T)%3A%20Result%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20...sources)%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20Expected%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20a%3A%202%0A%20%20b%3A%201%20%7C%202%0A%20%20c%3F%3A%201%0A%20%20d%3F%3A%201%20%7C%202%0A%20%20e%3A%202%0A%20%20f%3A%202%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20result%3A%20Expected%20%3D%20merge(%0A%20%20%7B%7D%20as%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20c%3F%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20d%3F%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20e%3F%3A%201%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%7D%20as%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%202%0A%20%20%20%20b%3F%3A%202%0A%20%20%20%20d%3F%3A%202%0A%20%20%20%20e%3A%202%0A%20%20%20%20f%3A%202%0A%20%20%7D%0A))

```
type Expected = {
  a: 2
  b: 1 | 2
  c?: 1
  d?: 1 | 2
  e: 2
  f: 2
}

// The return type should match `Expected` exactly. No intersections please!
const result: Expected = merge(
  {} as {
    a: 1
    b: 1
    c?: 1
    d?: 1
    e?: 1
  },
  {} as {
    a: 2
    b?: 2
    d?: 2
    e: 2
    f: 2
  }
)
```

Related question: [Typescript, merge object types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682569/typescript-merge-object-types)

Answer (score 2):

```
type Result<T extends object[]> = UnionToIntersection<T[number]>

/**
 * @author https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/10325032
 */
type UnionToIntersection<Union> =
  (Union extends any
    ? (argument: Union) => void
    : never
  ) extends (argument: infer Intersection) => void
      ? Intersection
      : never;
```

See [TypeScript Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsAPAFShAHsCAdgCbxQD2ARgFYQDGwA2gLoB8UAvFAKoECWZBDGQCSBfACd4dYPwKYGBRAFsKEcawBQGgPQAqXRqi6oAAQCGiYAAsy4qFeDAw8AFzbt8YGdoBrMgDc1ADNkMgB3ADpaMiVtRClJbQAmAA4UgHYkgEYU7SpaM2QAL0NjEyloBydXd09vP0DxEPComO0zbQBWAAYAZnTO1IA2bSy+pJ7epNLtDVBIbj4BIVEJKXpZNB5ZNnZDKAAKbYFsPEISKDMCEH2oKAB+Q7NxAHNlQmAXRdkASg42fxkXhEW5QL4ECCNfZ-XD4YikA7PN5KD5fXgEIJqKCrNTrGQCP7sAFAkF3MkPbFiXHSWSgu7gyFqADcWiCiAIGxOKNeEEwpzhF0oNHozBYBwiEvgZEQ4loCC+GB+XzgSFQmDYAG99uIIMAZQQoAB5ajSCJmeDwXgvAgHDUAXwANFAJREpTK5fAfho7Vp5tAAKI4SD0CBEDhQLV3MxfaZ3ChfLJQAA+UFjUFo9wT+yImagiZTaYgMf2QWLPo00QInigOtVnyggeD+DDnG5LwgB329supEjZOjedB8cH5IzWfJOfHZIguay+0dXbtPYjoIHabjufXUEnqdBRd35NLB6gPq9QA).

Comment: Ack, I should have been clearer. I actually used exactly that trick at first, but I would prefer to not have the intersection in the result type. I want it the `result` variable (in the example) to be **exactly** the `Expected` type. Sorry!

Comment: No worries! I've just noticed this solution is flawed anyway. The inferred type is very different than `Expected` and if requires an explicit type definition.

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE for TS4.1+

TypeScript 4.1 has (finally!) introduced support for [recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002), so now you *can* write `SpreadTuple` for arbitrary-length tuples, like this:

```
type SpreadTuple<T extends readonly any[]> =
  T extends [infer F] ? F :
  T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ?
  Spread<F, SpreadTuple<R>> : never;
```

(this also uses [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) introduced in TS4.0 to avoid the cumbersome `Tail` definition).

Soooo much nicer than the hoops you had to jump through before.  You can verify that this works in the original example code:

```
const result: Expected = merge(
  {} as {
    a: 1
    b: 1
    c?: 1
    d?: 1
    e?: 1
  },
  {} as {
    a: 2
    b?: 2
    d?: 2
    e: 2
    f: 2
  }
); // okay

const r = merge({ a: 1, b: 2 }, { b: "3", c: "4" }, { c: true, d: false });
// {  a: number;  b: string;  c: boolean;  d: boolean; }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200929#code/C4TwDgpgBAymBOECGATAKgVzAGwgHjSggA9gIA7FAZykVQHtzsQolyQBtAXQD4oBeALAAoKFEIkylGhwCW5AGYR4UAGJcoAfjVQAXCLETSFalDmLlagDRQAdPflKVAJQ3aDsBMhR5VNuHToWLh4zjx8ulDkEABuygDcIiIKGOQAxsCyjFAAtsoA5vhGUqb0AEYAVhAZ3DwAFPa2VPQY8GkQVJFoAJSRAd6YOEV8AN4eiMCt5FAA8pXVwLZIVFSy+eR1IwC+No3Nre1U3YnCW0nCaYxUwLQCuQUQm6yRAIw2ZZEATFA7UCNQHygACIAMxAmxpSJAgAsQJ+Nn+kKgwHgGAgNhQkQUSGwVGgW2OIgA9ES-mIkJFyBgcmUEmJAdd4PJ8vExEiyvR6Lg2KyoJiAZzueRWWdhMTSQA5JB5Gj0BRQBD0SDwTIdKDycRQADusmAAAtkeA1fqkDd5GlsBgUNBUtaFPIICgRKBILMwJlGDiAArwJXKUBSmUEPhCURkjgAaXV0wA1hAQHLxFxIraIPboigiMZpOJI24oFHKbFLFsOHGE-K0FwTuKoABheg5HLZRXK1U0BS+nJQAAyrEoUGc2t1BtT6cd0cHedoEBwSHambKLBd0A1PbzzqNnkCPr9KtkHTwPZszhsUckJho5cTfYAZFBr-KwgIPP8OF7JxHk733xoAD5QAAosQFpWvgzi-jYY4OigfBbDWwgkuIW6Jv8jTHnY9hDqKK7bt4R4niGUB1B4SG7m2B40GuyJ6qafKMAA5DcJCyNck7OB495erIaQxgRQEgZa1p4I+vY2KJYQ8KRpLkf6lHscO+qGpANAmsxglgVA0EZpxUDcbxoQ2MBoHCRJNgzO6WTkN6vptiAgaHpJUlhmRtlyWqGqnopBorqptFmukQk2pQaYwTYan0eQTFZqxAW9rp+l8V5xlBXgFketZ2CySq9nSo5PDifGN7hNJelufuHnTF5OpKb5NF0eaQVaSF44oOF-kxWxa66f0qDZe2-FeelVk2XuAZ5VQoR8Peok9s53RZiUVEWCoMxaOGUYaqJMzfjM05bHoUTFvA8RAA)

---

Pre-TS4.1 answer:

The short answer is that you **can't** do it for an arbitrary number of values.  The slightly longer answer is that you **shouldn't try** to do it, since the natural recursive definition [will not work](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980) and the various ways you can trick the compiler into doing it are [officially frowned upon](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897#issuecomment-401418254).

If you are willing to support up to some reasonable but finite maximum number of arguments, you **can** do it.  Indeed, the [standard library definition of `Object.assign()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.3.1/lib/lib.es2015.core.d.ts#L280-L313) currently is just a few overloads with intersections.  And though this [might change sometime](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28323), it seems to work well enough for people.

Assuming we take `Spread<L, R>` from [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49683575/2887218) as a starting point, we can make our own `SpreadTuple` that works for anything up to a fixed length:

```
type Tail<L extends any[]> =
  ((...l: L) => void) extends ((h: infer H, ...t: infer T) => void) ? T : never;

type SpreadTuple<T extends {}[], L extends number = T['length']> = L extends 0 ? never : L extends 1 ? T[0] : Spread<T[0], SpreadTuple1<Tail<T>>>
type SpreadTuple1<T extends {}[], L extends number = T['length']> = L extends 0 ? never : L extends 1 ? T[0] : Spread<T[0], SpreadTuple2<Tail<T>>>
type SpreadTuple2<T extends {}[], L extends number = T['length']> = L extends 0 ? never : L extends 1 ? T[0] : Spread<T[0], SpreadTuple3<Tail<T>>>
type SpreadTuple3<T extends {}[], L extends number = T['length']> = L extends 0 ? never : L extends 1 ? T[0] : Spread<T[0], SpreadTuple4<Tail<T>>>
type SpreadTuple4<T extends {}[], L extends number = T['length']> = L extends 0 ? never : L extends 1 ? T[0] : Spread<T[0], SpreadTuple5<Tail<T>>>
type SpreadTuple5<T extends {}[], L extends number = T['length']> = L extends 0 ? never : L extends 1 ? T[0] : Spread<T[0], SpreadTuple6<Tail<T>>>
type SpreadTuple6<T extends {}[], L extends number = T['length']> = L extends 0 ? never : L extends 1 ? T[0] : Spread<T[0], SpreadTuple7<Tail<T>>>
type SpreadTuple7<T extends {}[], L extends number = T['length']> = L extends 0 ? never : L extends 1 ? T[0] : Spread<T[0], SpreadTuple8<Tail<T>>>
type SpreadTuple8<T extends {}[], L extends number = T['length']> = L extends 0 ? never : L extends 1 ? T[0] : Spread<T[0], SpreadTuple9<Tail<T>>>
type SpreadTuple9<T extends {}[], L extends number = T['length']> = L extends 0 ? never : L extends 1 ? T[0] : Spread<T[0], SpreadTupleX<Tail<T>>>
type SpreadTupleX<T extends {}[]> = T[number]; // give up
```

I did it that way so you can see how to easily extend it to any length you care about.  You can do it without `Tail` if you're comfortable hardcoding a lot of `Spread<Spread<Spread<....>>>` around.

Anyway, now this works:

```
// use default parameter R to expand result to easy-to-digest type
function merge<T extends object[], R = SpreadTuple<T>>(...sources: T): { [K in keyof R]: R[K] } {
  return Object.assign({}, ...sources);
}

const result: Expected = merge(
  {} as {
    a: 1
    b: 1
    c?: 1
    d?: 1
    e?: 1
  },
  {} as {
    a: 2
    b?: 2
    d?: 2
    e: 2
    f: 2
  }
)
//const result: {
//  c?: 1 | undefined;
//  a: 2;
//  e: 2;
//  f: 2;
//  b: 1 | 2;
//  d: 1 | 2 | undefined;
//}
```

And let's just try one with more than two arguments:

```
const r = merge({ a: 1, b: 2 }, { b: "3", c: "4" }, { c: true, d: false });
// {  a: number;  b: string;  c: boolean;  d: boolean; }
```

Looks good to me.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!