# Typescript: Merging types (vs intersecting them)

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

Consider the following

```js
type MergeFn = <K1 extends string, V1, K2 extends string, V2>(
   k1: K1, v1: V1,
   k2: K2, v2: V2
) => ???

let mergeFn: MergeFn // implementation not relevant to question
```

What would I have to fill in for `???` so that

```
mergeFn(
  "hello", 1,
  "typescript", 2
)
```

has type `{ hello: number, typescript: number }`.

I tried

`??? = { [k in K1]: V1 } & { [k in K2]: V2 }`

but the result will be

`{ hello: number } & { typescript: number }`.

(Applying `type Id<T> = { [k in keyof T]: T[k] }` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682569/typescript-merge-object-types) did not help either.)

[Example in the typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNhAhgOwDwBUB8UC8UDeUA2gNZQCWyUJEIA9gGZToC6AXM6S1AL4BQfUJCgBjBClyxxaQgAtyHZAFcAtgCMIAJ15QAZASjBZWiItUbtPTAKHQAsloDmEAGJU8qANIBGKBAAewBDIACYAzlBhwJqUjgA0UABq3gmeAEx+gcHhkdGxCYlpmAAUfFDl1N4cPgkAblVJKWUVJGnVaXVtSWl8AJS42PBIMsRklFA+7I06+oSkFFTpU4W81nwidMhRUCpOrsgcDprObpJKoRAMlBAhAhtbwIYQ23i7x-ulFVAARPLfCQAWOLNcrfIwmf5QAF9PhAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do it is to use a single conditional mapped type instead of an intersection:

```
type MergeFn = <K1 extends string, V1, K2 extends string, V2>(
    k1: K1, v1: V1,
    k2: K2, v2: V2
) => { [K in K1 | K2]: K extends K1 ? V1 : V2}
```

which produces

```
const test = mergeFn(
    "hi", 4,
    "there", 4
)
/* const test: {
    hi: number;
    there: number;
} */
```

---

When you say the `Id<T>` "didn't help" I assume you mean that the compiler decided to show you a type alias name like `Id<A & B>` instead of expanding it out for you.  I've found in such cases that the way to deal with it is to pass through an intermediate conditional type, like this:

```
type Expand<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never
```

If I use that on your original code:

```
type MergeFn = <K1 extends string, V1, K2 extends string, V2>(
    k1: K1, v1: V1,
    k2: K2, v2: V2
) => Expand<Record<K1, V1> & Record<K2, V2>>
```

I get the same output:

```
const test = mergeFn(
    "hi", 4,
    "there", 4
)
/* const test: {
    hi: number;
    there: number;
} */
```

So either way should work for you.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBhA9sAJgSwC7YxABsBZEGGCTJAbwCglGlcBPSpEiAJwHMIAxYEgC8SADwBpAIxIIAD1wQsUJFFxdswHgBokANSm6JAJlkKlmFWo1bde4wD4AFAyZuA1lIBcSaboBu3vqGrm6M7sY+JgGR+sahSACUIg60SADaEkiavjIAPr7GALpRZorKuUgA-MFIPvZIAL4J8BhqSJC8AsA+nF2CIkgArlgQAGaaVACEdC1tuMzQC6KdfIIuYUwARAAW2Fu6ACzaCW5buDvcEAdIhwmJCQD0AFRIrcDtimo+9JuMez5gEMwAAjbgAblOTAuV0BwLBXEhbkaSGejzozTooEgsAQyAAonI4FhaAlWOxCcTMGIACqpUQ0soWFSaMbcJAAVWqaUy2SE7ggLDQY05JU5mSKTTqSGAEH83FmbnJyD6ayEokkMnk5UsqnUmh0wSMpm1zL1NkN9mcUPCQT8SEC9RCfyQESixhi9XibmSwlSlJAWDEACUIK0uNT7QZUgAyJCh8ORj1xBwOOYfBarbq9bhqwYjTDjSaYGbpz5LQZZ9Y2pC7fZHE4u86XLjXI73J6vd7l76kl0AmXwiE1mGtuGg4fI1HojFAA)

Comment: That's precisely what I meant with "did't work". If I was only concerned with the resulting type, I'd have also been fine with `A & B` but I was looking for pretty compiler output.