# Generic function to merge multiple TypeScript enums

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums, typescript4.0

I'm attempting to write a generic function to merge multiple enums. The hope is that this function would accomplish the same as the following:

```
enum Mammals {
  Humans = 'Humans',
  Bats = 'Bats',
  Dolphins = 'Dolphins',
}

enum Reptiles {
  Snakes = 'Snakes',
  Alligators = 'Alligators',
  Lizards = 'Lizards',
}

const Animals = {
 ...Mammals,
 ...Reptiles,
}

type Animals = Mammals | Reptiles;
```

First Attempt:

```
export const mergeEnums = <T extends any[]>(...enums: T): T[number] => {
  return {
    ...enums,
  };
};

// Results in Animals: typeof Mammals | typeof Reptiles
const Animals = mergeEnums(Mammals, Reptiles);
```

Unfortunately, the union type is not quite right. TypeScript does not allow the keys to be accessed. Example type error: `Property 'Snakes' does not exist on type 'typeof Mammals | typeof Reptiles'.`

Second Attempt:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I,
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

export const mergeEnums = <T extends any[]>(
  ...enums: T
): UnionToIntersection<T[number]> => {
  return {
    ...enums,
  } as UnionToIntersection<T[number]>;
};

// Results in Animals: typeof Mammals & typeof Reptiles
const Animals = mergeEnums(Mammals, Reptiles);
```

This does allow for key access, but results in a return type of `never` when the same key exists in more than one enum, which is a possibility in my usage.

Is it possible to achieve a solution that's functionally the same as `Animals: Mammals | Reptiles`?

Comment: "when the same key exists in more than one enum, which is a possibility in my usage" seems like a weird edge case; why would you be doing this or allowing it?  In any case, other than the variadic input, it looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682569/typescript-merge-object-types).  I'd be happy to write up a new answer which uses recursion to do it on a tuple of inputs, but I don't really see it as much of an improvement over just `UnionToIntersection` unless you can articulate why you want to be allowing enum keys to collide that way.

Comment: I agree with jcalz. What _would_ you expect when the same key appears in two enums? Its value cannot be both the value from the first enum _and_ the value from another enum at the same time, since two non-identical primitives have no overlap. `never` is the only type that makes sense in such scenario.

Comment: Eh, I wrote up an answer anyway 

Comment: I'm merging supported asset tickers from various financial exchanges into a global list of tickers as part of my actual usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to try to emulate in the type system what the spread operator does at runtime with colliding properties, you could do it by adapting my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682569/typescript-merge-object-types).  It starts out like this:

```
type OptionalPropertyNames<T> =
  { [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never }[keyof T];

type SpreadProperties<L, R, K extends keyof L & keyof R> =
  { [P in K]: L[P] | Exclude<R[P], undefined> };

type Id<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never

// Type of { ...L, ...R }
type Spread<L, R> = Id<
  // Properties in L that don't exist in R
  & Pick<L, Exclude<keyof L, keyof R>>
  // Properties in R with types that exclude undefined
  & Pick<R, Exclude<keyof R, OptionalPropertyNames<R>>>
  // Properties in R, with types that include undefined, that don't exist in L
  & Pick<R, Exclude<OptionalPropertyNames<R>, keyof L>>
  // Properties in R, with types that include undefined, that exist in L
  & SpreadProperties<L, R, OptionalPropertyNames<R> & keyof L>
>;
```

Optional properties are quite the headache, since if I have an object like `{a: string}` and spread an object of type `{a?: number}` into it, the resulting object will be an `{a: string | number}`.  All the caveats from the other question apply here: there are very many edge cases.  The default intersection you get from `Object.assign()` or a generic spread is, frankly, not much worse than the mess above and is a lot simpler.  I'd only recommend going with `Spread<L, R>` in place of `L & R` if you are sure your use case warrants it.

---

Anyway, moving on to the variadic tuple part.  TypeScript 4.1 will introduce recursive conditional types (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40002](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002)) so you can represent your `Merge<T>` as a recursive operation on `Spread<L, R>`:

```
type Merge<T extends readonly any[]> = 
  T extends readonly [infer H, ...infer R] ? Spread<H, Merge<R>> : {}

export const mergeEnums = <T extends any[]>(
  ...enums: T
) => {
  return {
    ...enums,
  } as any as Merge<T>;
};
```

This should work as you expect:

```
enum Mammals {
  Humans = 'Humans',
  Bats = 'Bats',
  Dolphins = 'Dolphins',
}

enum Reptiles {
  Snakes = 'Snakes',
  Alligators = 'Alligators',
  Lizards = 'Lizards',
}

const Animals = mergeEnums(Mammals, Reptiles);
type Animals = typeof Animals[keyof typeof Animals];

const Animals = mergeEnums(Mammals, Reptiles);
/* const Animals: {
    readonly Humans: Mammals.Humans;
    readonly Bats: Mammals.Bats;
    readonly Dolphins: Mammals.Dolphins;
    readonly Snakes: Reptiles.Snakes;
    readonly Alligators: Reptiles.Alligators;
    readonly Lizards: Reptiles.Lizards;
} */
type Animals = typeof Animals[keyof typeof Animals];
// type Animals = Mammals | Reptiles
```

and if you allow for collision, you get what I hope is your desired outcome:

```
enum Reptiles {
  Humans = 'They Have Discovered That We Are Alien Invaders; KILL THEM ALL',
  Snakes = 'Snakes',
  Alligators = 'Alligators',
  Lizards = 'Lizards',
}

const Animals = mergeEnums(Mammals, Reptiles);
/* const Animals: {
    readonly Bats: Mammals.Bats;
    readonly Dolphins: Mammals.Dolphins;
    readonly Humans: Reptiles.Humans;
    readonly Snakes: Reptiles.Snakes;
    readonly Alligators: Reptiles.Alligators;
    readonly Lizards: Reptiles.Lizards;
} */

type Animals = typeof Animals[keyof typeof Animals];
// type Animals = Mammals.Bats | Mammals.Dolphins | Reptiles
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201027#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwAoCcmR1ADk0BbCAZwB4AVAPigF4AoKKAbygG0BpKBFFADWEEEgBmUGgF0AtAH4AXBwC+UCAA9gEFABMKULAgDGQ2gBooPBvKtRlKCADcIOKCq4ixkmQG5mzKCQUADKYDgQaLq4+K6IlFQAMpYASpZ8mtp6Bl4SUIlQAGTConkpDCxsnFxY-II80sqJNdJQAD5QAKIaxhgArroQVCktln16EOICELoMKv6B4NAAkrq0FVLqWjr6deKusFC21XwCJd6wjbC8rWoOzq4BAPRPUktQeZwAdD-JUD9fFLuRbBMIRKJJVIbVZUVhQF6GPAEeIGM4FYAACzQwCgulQAHIcZoEBQcWcUnDikZTJCuj1+oMqLlJH9mVBynQ4QiYsiEJQ6uyoAB3BCYqBBfmY7FbXoDaDjQZTRy6SmGExmNJ02WMtmauCIVCYHlxEAkcjUDmctjcpFxPmowSakViiUGKVklDa+UTJUzSzu3EEokaEke-Kq6kayzdL1UfXIdDYW2EU1kBLlSxsxJ0K3w17Gwj2gVO0UY8VLN1Yj1eqAKybTXT+qtbUMCxKqsGRaLJlG0vXwBNGnup83DBjFLOcugLCVQACyrgA5kMaFssrtwXiUBgQFA0CgQFxpBtV5kdgZN6gd9wBPs3AAJSwA28HFKtWydiGP+dLoYc+yqAEmhgEghBQMYqCklA5A4MunQoH0pAGIwUC0Gu557geR50AAFHCAI6IhFDKDQzAAJRMAw7BwhEwB9DggjUWwbAEQhSHmHCahoAY+67txP6wSu07MPMQFsfOZCkJgBhMVA96IfuyFQPi8lSSgFD4hxbAAELYkp+K6cAGlaVAAAiSAYGAGICPp5mWdZ6maSJYmIeyEADhg-KyapilMMpNAYqIcloC4ZkkhBLgRLoUjNgA6tAACCERQAlGB8oIywoE4USuBQvhWMsiQFDQ96dHOKVFU5bAhOgIj6TVaB1VVKUYGli7YqB+mpW1HU4MZcKJAgABeaA4LsKH4oNI1jf1KgBBB6k4glKAIFJGBKTBcFsRQOFzpJ0mpO5iCeRQZH+E8ABU4GQUtK1rcRHBwmwl7bruPnqcoe2kPdXzvXlT1QC916GQ9X0-SD-jMYDXZXrudlWTZn37etXzww5-1Q0Du4NXVygpEdCAnV8OOUJDzFYy1PXAJ1eME0T3UIO11N9WTz0w69+TDaN+i0x5lBfFN3P-WoF2vM8V0LVBy2rdJyiyWzUSw1AINI990lfBDAMU2jiMSWrKM6+prPQ4rHN-bzx3839xsUyTD343zFDE7VpNa+z14M0zNNuY7Xye71GPk+7u6CzNFuE-zof6P4ItPAEs7S-dfkSnkifSZ4pSSCnkhp+t0jna8Cd3dJflgyXHQO5bFDMAiRcy+tpfI07IPtHrP2GwYFd05QQA)