# Typescript generic syntax for merge

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
type OptionalPropertyNames<T> =
  { [K in keyof T]-?: ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? K : never) } [keyof T];
```

I understand most of it but can't make sense of the :

```js
{} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? K : never
```

what does that code block represent?
Under which condition would the conditional be truthy?

Found the syntax in a [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682569/typescript-merge-object-types)

Comment: TS allows the unsound but convenient assignment of an object without a known property to one with an optional property.  So `{}` extends `{a?: string}` for example. This is not true for `{}` and `{a: string | undefined}`, so this check turns out to be one of the few ways to detect optionality of properties.

Comment: I’m on mobile so I can’t write this up just yet.

Answer (score 2):

The intent of `OptionalPropertyNames<T>` is to find the keys of `T` which correspond to [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties), and we can see that it works (at least for object types without [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) or other edge cases):

```
type OptionalPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?:
    ({} extends { [P in K]: T[K] } ? K : never)
}[keyof T];

interface Foo {
    opt?: string,
    req: string | undefined
}

type Opt = OptionalPropertyNames<Foo> // "opt"
```

This works by looking at each property `K` from the keys in `T`, and checking whether, essentially `{} extends Pick<T, K>` (the type `{[P in K]: T[K]}` is equivalent to [the `Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) at least in this instance where `K extends keyof T`). So for the `opt` property we're checking `{} extends {opt?: string}` and for the `req` property we're checking `{} extends {req: string | undefined}`.

For `{} extends {req: string | undefined}` this is obviously false.  If you have a value of type `{}` you cannot safely treat it as if it's a value of type `{req: string | undefined}`.  For `{} extends {opt?: string}`, though, TypeScript considers that to be *true*.  That lets us distinguish between required and optional properties, and therefore `OptionalPropertyNames<Foo>` is `"opt"`.

That's the answer to the question as asked.  But wait, why is `{} extends {opt?: string}` true?

---

Well, it's very convenient to allow assigning an object type without a known property to an object type with an optional property:

```
interface Bar {
    req: string | undefined
}
let bar: Bar = { req: "req" };

interface Foo extends Bar {
    opt?: string;
}
let foo: Foo = bar; // allowed by convenience
```

It would be quite annoying if that last line failed.  We know what `bar` is a valid `Foo` because `bar` is missing the `opt` property. The compiler sort of shrugs and says "well, the type `Bar` doesn't have a known `opt` property, so that's kind of like saying it is *missing* an `opt` property, which is compatible with the optional property from `Foo`".  But that's not really a [sound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) assumption to make.

Object types in TypeScript are *open* and *extendible* as opposed to *sealed* or *exact* (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)), in order to support [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system).  An object can always turn out to have more properties than are to be found in the object's type:

```
interface Baz extends Bar {
    opt: number;
}
let baz: Baz = { opt: 123, req: "req" };
bar = baz; // allowed by structural subtyping
```

Here a value with a numeric `opt` property has been assigned to `bar`, and that assignment is legal and type safe by structural subtyping.  But put together, these two rules can lead to trouble.  While the compiler rightfully complains about this assignment:

```
foo = baz; // error! Types of property 'opt' are incompatible.
```

It fails to notice if you do the same assignment in two steps:

```
bar = baz; // allowed by subtyping
foo = bar; // allowed by convenience
```

And that means everything compilers just fine and you don't know anything's wrong until runtime:

```
if (foo.opt) {
    foo.opt.toUpperCase(); // no compiler error, but:
    //  RUNTIME ERROR: foo.opt.toUpperCase is not a function
}
```

Oops.

So this is one of the places where TypeScript's type system is inconsistent.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#42479](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42479).) and the above definition uses it to detect optional properties.

---

In the annoying alternate universe where the compiler did not allow such an assignment, you could probably still detect optional properties with something like:

```
type OptionalPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?:
    (Partial<Pick<T, K>> extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never)
}[keyof T];
```

since [the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) should produce something not assignable to `T` unless `T` already has all optional properties.  But this is even more of a digression than the last section, so I'll stop here.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Bw3C8AIQgxpIsiXioqhYIciCYFQWAILE-C0HqnB0AwugCvCrHsZxzgME4Lhbh4Xi+P4gRURIYRAA)