# Typescript: Property name collisions in types vs interfaces

Tags: typescript, types, interface

Let's say I have 2 types with the same property name but different data types:

```
type A = {
  myProperty:string
}

type B = {
  myProperty:number
}
```

If I extend both using an interface, I see an error as expected:

```
interface C extends A, B {}
```

```
Interface 'C' cannot simultaneously extend types 'A' and 'B'.
  Named property 'myProperty' of types 'A' and 'B' are not identical.
```

But if I use a type to extend both, there is no exception. In this case, what's the resulting data type of `myProperty`? Is there a way to check the resulting data type?

```
type C = A & B; // no error
```

I can't set a value for `myProperty` (string or number) if C is declared as a type. What's the best way to handle this scenario?

```
function F(myParameter:C) {
  console.log(myParameter);
}

F({myProperty: 90});
```

```
(property) myProperty: never
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
index.ts(3, 3): The expected type comes from property 'myProperty' which is declared here on type 'C'
```

Same error if I call the function as `F({myProperty: 'test data'});`.

Playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-dglbq5?file=/index.ts

Comment: What do you mean by "handle" the scenario?  The property is of type `string & number` which is [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type), which, by definition, you can never get a value of.  A value of both type `A` *and* type `B` would have to have *both* a `string` *and* a `number` value for its property, which is not possible.

Comment: *"Is there a way to check the resulting data type?"* yes, you can use an `Expand` utility type to see the fully computed type. See [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3PG2W).

Comment: Do you maybe need a utility type which lets you intersect conflicting type definitions without creating any `never` types?

Comment: @TobiasS. Thanks for the pointer to Expand utility type. I wasn't aware of that, very helpful!

Comment: @TobiasS. How would the utility class handle intersection while avoiding conflicts? A sample?

Comment: @jcalz: I meant that `myProperty` should either be number or string, depending on how Typescript types operate, or if there is a way to tell Typescript whether the first or the second operand to '&' takes precedence when there is a conflict. But since the resulting type is 'never', I don't know how to assign a particular value (string or number) to it.

Comment: So then you don't want an intersection, but some other type operation which combines two object types in some other way.  Maybe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682569/typescript-merge-object-types ?

Comment: @jcalz: That link is very useful. The simple [one-liner answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814101/174926) is what I am after. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to intersect two conflicting types but still want to instantiate the resulting type, there are multiple options to handle it. **Note** that both solutions will not resolve conflicts for properties nested deeper than the first level.

Let's say we have two interfaces `A` and `B` which we want to intersect.

```
interface A {
    a: string
    b: string
}

interface B {
    a: number
    c: string
}
```

---

The first option could be to omit the conflicting property from the resulting type.

```
type IntersectByOmitting<A, B> = {
    [K in keyof (A & B) as K extends keyof A & keyof B 
      ? [A[K] & B[K]] extends [never] 
        ? never 
        : K 
      : K
    ]: K extends keyof A ? A[K] : B[K & keyof B]
}

type T0 = IntersectByOmitting<A, B>
//   ^? type T0 = { b: string; c: string; }
```

Since `a` resolves to `never` in the intersection, it will be omitted from the resulting type.

---

As you said in the comment, you may want to have a union of the conflicting properties instead.

```
type IntersectByUnion<A, B> = {
    [K in keyof (A & B)]: K extends (keyof A & keyof B) ? 
      [A[K] & B[K]] extends [never] 
        ? A[K] | B[K] 
        : A[K] & B[K]
      : K extends keyof A ? A[K] : B[K & keyof B]
}

type T1 = IntersectByUnion<A, B>
// type T1 = {
//    a: string | number;
//    b: string;
//    c: string;
// }
```

The type of `a` is now `string | number`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEFUG9ir6hALlQGcIZwBzXfAI2LIrGoF9hRJZEVUAhbGniKowAVwC2tWINRIG5KsDbAIATwAOaAJKcYJKEgi9VAeXEgIEKgB50AGj4A+VAF4B+VAG0A0qnCoAayhVAHs4VAAKTAAyPgBKAhJUXygAD2gwABMkoNDwmMDgsL5UGTwAfi90HwBdVFjeWrq0jOyvMCgAN1g6svxKju6YUo8PYl8+8Zka8dQWqCycovzUSurvOuJG31jc4t4apXY1TVQdaD0DI1UAVTAQELBbB15nNxwPHz8wQrzIgt4cRmyTm6QWbQiexWu2W8VWI1GnnWdQaTVBrSSnkGPQRo3hyNQAB8+LVcaNiATURtJiD5otfsVMGtSVsvjC-gcjioNGgACoABlcZ10+kMxjMFiszGeTmAAHo5fgAHrlY481C8gCMQvOsFF1zuDye9llCuV5SAA)

Comment: Thanks ... your second snippet for the union addresses my use case. Btw, typescriptlang's `//   ^?` is very cool and handy. Learnt that from your samples!