# Type patterns for applying options in functions

Tags: typescript

What is a good/sane pattern for typing options in functions?

```js
type DummyType<T>=T 

type Options = {
  optionX: boolean
  optionY: boolean
  ...
}

const exampleFn = <T,O extends Options>(arg: T, options?: Partial<O>)=>{
  // opts below is a combination of `options` and the relevant defaults
  // opts should ALWAYS match `O`
  const opts: O = {
    optionX: false,
    optionY: true, ...options
  }
  console.log(arg, opts)

  ...

  // return type may be different based on supplied `O`
  return { whatever: arg } as unknown as DummyType<O['optionX']>
}
```

Ideally:

- options `O` should be inferred based on supplied parameter `options` - after applying any defaults
- if no, or only some options are supplied, then default options should be applied - as per `opts`
- generic `O` should contain the type of `opts` with defaults applied - as it could change the shape of the returned output.

Comment: WHy do you create `opts` const ?

Comment: `opts` is just the final complete version of options provided to the function, including any defaults - and so will never change.

Comment: Do you want the compiler to keep track of the actual property *values* passed in (like, specifically `true` vs `false`)?  Or just which *keys* are passed in?

Comment: I suppose you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mM1QZm) but I don't know that it's good/sane.  There are TS issues surrounding accurately representing generic spread/merge types, and the more we work on that the less "sane" things appear.  In any case it looks like your typings are a bit backwards, since your `O` is the *output* of a merge operation, so it's unlikely you'll get the compiler to infer it from `options`.  The reverse (have `O` be the type of `options` and then compute the output type) is at least plausibly inferrable. Does that address your question? Do you want me to write...

Comment: ...up an answer? If so please comment and mention @jcalz to notify me.  If not you can still notify me and tell me what's missing with my suggestion.

Comment: @jcalz - yes the compiler should know the actual property values passed in - as they shape the type of the output.

Comment: @jcalz - the [solution](https://tsplay.dev/mM1QZm) you provided is a good pattern.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your typings seem backwards to me.  Your `O` type is only really applicable to the *output* of merging an object with `options`, but the only type from which the compiler can easily infer is the type of `options`, the *input*.  If we switch things around so that `O` is the type of `options`, then we can try to compute the output type in terms of `O` explicitly.

---

One issue is that when you write `{ optionX: false, optionY: true, ...options}` and `options` is of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type like `O`, the compiler *approximates* the type of the result with an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), like `{ optionX: false, optionY: true } & O`.  That type is fine if `O` doesn't have the keys `optionX` or `optionY`, but fails pretty badly if it does have those keys.  A plain intersection fails to capture the results of overwriting properties.

To do better we need to start writing our own helper types and asserting that a spread results in a value of those types.  It's probably out of scope to go into exactly how to best do this and what the pitfalls are.  You can look at [Typescript, merge object types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49682569/2887218) for details.  For now let's pick something that works well enough as long as the merged object doesn't have declared optional properties which happen to be missing:

```
type Merge<T, U> = { [K in keyof T | keyof U]: 
  K extends keyof U ? U[K] : K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never };
const merge = <T, U>(t: T, u: U) => ({ ...t, ...u }) as Merge<T, U>;
```

Let's test that:

```
const test = merge(
    { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
    { b: "two", c: "three", d: "four" }
);
/* const test: {
    a: number;
    b: string;
    c: string;
    d: string;
} */
console.log(test.c.toUpperCase()) // "THREE"
```

Looks good. The compiler understands that `b` and `c` are overwritten with `string` values instead of `number` values.

---

Okay, so here's how I'd approach this:

```
const defaultOpts = { optionX: false, optionY: true } as const;
type DefaultOpts = typeof defaultOpts;

function exampleFn<T, O extends Partial<Options> = {}>(
    arg: T, options?: O) {
    const o = options ?? {} as O; // assert here
    const opts = merge(defaultOpts, o);
    console.log(arg, opts)
    const ret: DummyType<Merge<DefaultOpts, O>['optionX']> = opts.optionX; // okay
    return ret;
}
```

First, I moved the set of default options into its own variable named `defaultOptions`, and had the compiler compute its type and gave that the name `DefaultOptions`.  When we merge `options` of type `O` into that, the result will be of type `Merge<DefaultOpts, O>`.

Then we want `exampleFn()` to be called in two ways: either with two arguments, in which case `options` will be of type `O`, or with one argument, in which case `options` will be `undefined` and we'd like `O` to [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to being just the empty type `{}`.

So I assign `o` to be a value of type `O`, and I need to assert that `{}` is of type `O` when `options` is `undefined`, because it's technically possible for this not to be true (but I'm not worrying about that possibility).

Then `opts` is of type `Merge<DefaultOptions, O>`.

For the returned value I just index into `opts` with `optionX` to give a value of type `DummyType<Merge<DefaultOpts, O>['optionX']>` (because `DummyType<T>` is just the identity type; if you change `DummyType` then you need to change the code to match, or use an assertion as you were doing before).

---

Okay, let's test that typing:

```
exampleFn({}, {}) // false
exampleFn({}, { optionX: true }) // true
exampleFn({}, { optionX: false }) // false
exampleFn({}); // false
exampleFn({}, { optionY: false, optionX: undefined }) // undefined
```

This all works well enough, I think.  Note that it's a bit weird for someone to explicitly pass in `undefined` for a property, but by default [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) do accept that.

Note that the following call gives the wrong output type:

```
exampleFn({}, Math.random() < 0.5 ? {} : { optionX: true }) // true | undefined
```

That's because my definition of `Merge` doesn't take into account the possibility that the `optionX` property of the passed-in `options` argument might be missing.  It assumes it's present-and-`undefined`, and so the output type is mistakenly produced as `true | undefined` instead of the actual `true | false`.  I'm not worried too much about this; the point here is just to note that there are potential pitfalls with just about any definition of `Merge`, and you'll need to decide where to stop caring.  I assume that options argument isn't going to generally be of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) so the mistake here doesn't matter much.  But you should definitely test against your use cases and tweak `Merge` if you have to.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgrgWwSAKuCAeFA+KBeKFAKCNEigHkxgBLAewDsBnfKAbyKi6juvoYAaALigAjOnQA2EAIYNO3XrUYBNEeKmz5AXxJloAWQgAnAOaYUAGigBVXATZQA2gGkoNBlADWEEHQBmhFAAPt6+AbYAuiJuEAAewBAMACYsPn6BNlAA-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)