# Is it possible to constrain object's attribute values[] based on object's other attribute value for a typed array of objects?

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to define a typed array of objects. The objects sharing the same generic type structure and the generic type accepting a type argument to provide more specificity (constraining the allowed values of the object's other (array) attribute).

## Example

A typed array should enforce its elements to adhere to rules like:

`{ tableName: 'roles', ...}` should constrain `returnColumns` to have only  `'id' and/or 'name'` and
`{ tableName: 'permissions', ...}` should constrain `returnColumns` to have only `'id' and/or 'permission'`

e.g.

```
[ 
   {
      tableName: 'roles',
      returnColumns: ['id', 'name']  // should be OK
    },
    {
      tableName: 'roles',
      returnColumns: ['name']  // should be OK
    },
    {
      tableName: 'permissions',
      returnColumns: ['id', 'permission']  //  should be OK
    },
    {
      tableName: 'permissions',
      returnColumns: ['id']  //  should be OK
    },
    {
      tableName: 'roles',
      returnColumns: ['id', 'permission']  //  should not be OK, permission belongs to permissions
    },
]
```

## Breakdown

### Part 1: working typed objects

In the example below, the single objects are correctly typed:

```
type JoinTable<T> = {
  tableName: T;
  returnColumns: TableColumns<TypeOfTableName<T>>[];
};

const rolesExample1: JoinTable<'roles'> = {
  tableName: 'roles',
  returnColumns: ['id', 'name'] // OK, because roles is only allowed id and/or name
};

const rolesExample2: JoinTable<'roles'> = {
  tableName: 'roles',
  returnColumns: ['id', 'permission'] // Should fail, because roles is only allowed id and name, and permission is not available to roles
};

const permsExample3: JoinTable<'permissions'> = {
  tableName: 'permissions',
  returnColumns: ['id', 'permission'] // OK, because permissions is only allowed id and/or permission
};

const permsExample4: JoinTable<'permissions'> = {
  tableName: 'permissions',
  returnColumns: ['id', 'name'] // Should fail, because permissions is only allowed id and/or permission, and name is not available to permissions
};
```

### Part 2: failing typed array of objects

In the example below, we see the failure:

```
type JoinTable<T> = {
  tableName: T;
  returnColumns: TableColumns<TypeOfTableName<T>>[];
};

type JoinColumns<T> = T extends unknown
  ? TableColumns<TypeOfTableName<T>>
  : never;

// This code allows for returnColumns elements to be any value of any table
export type Joins<T extends TableName> = {
  joins: (Omit<JoinTable<RelatedTableName<T>>, 'returnColumns'> & {
      returnColumns: JoinColumns<RelatedTableName<T>>[]
  })[]
};


const combinedJoins: Joins<'role_permissions'> = {
  joins: [
    {
      tableName: 'roles',
      returnColumns: ['id', 'name', 'permission'] // Should (but doesn't) fail, because permission is not available to roles
    },
    {
      tableName: 'permissions',
      returnColumns: ['id', 'name', 'permission'] // Should (but doesn't) fail, because name is not available to permissions
    },
    {
      tableName: 'roles',
      returnColumns: ['id', 'name', 'uh-oh'] // Should fail (and does) because nothing supports uh-oh
    },
    {
      tableName: 'roles',
      returnColumns: ['id', 'name']  // should be OK
    },
    {
      tableName: 'roles',
      returnColumns: ['name']  // should be OK
    },
    {
      tableName: 'permissions',
      returnColumns: ['id', 'permission']  //  should be OK
    },
    
  ]
};
```

### Part 3: where it started

I originally started with the following variation of the Joins type:

```
export type Joins<T extends TableName> = {
  joins: JoinTable<RelatedTableName<T>>[]
};
```

This worked when there was only one object type in the array, but with two object types, suddenly the values of returnColumns is constrained to only those values which all the objects in the array share.

e.g. if there was both an roles and a permissions object in the array, the values of returnColumns could only be id which both types have in common.

### The data schema and supporting types: Database, TableName, TableColumns, TableRelationships etc

```typescript
export interface Database {
  golf_scores: {
    Tables: {
      permissions: {
        Row: {
          id: number;
          permission: string;
        };
        Relationships: [];
      };
      role_permissions: {
        Row: {
          id_permissions: number;
          id_roles: number;
        };

        Relationships: [
          {
            referencedRelation: 'permissions';
            referencedColumns: ['id'];
          },
          {
            referencedRelation: 'roles';
            referencedColumns: ['id'];
          }
        ];
      };
      roles: {
        Row: {
          id: number;
          name: string;
        };
        Relationships: [];
      };
    };
  }
}

export type TableName = keyof Database['golf_scores']['Tables'];


export type TableColumns<T extends TableName> =
  keyof Database['golf_scores']['Tables'][T]['Row'];

export type TypeOfTableName<T> = T extends TableName ? T : never;

type TablesRelationships<T extends TableName> =
  Database['golf_scores']['Tables'][T]['Relationships'];

export type RelatedTableName<T extends TableName> =
  TablesRelationships<T>[number]['referencedRelation'];
```

(Note: working examples here: ([typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2&ssl=74&ssc=7&pln=63&pc=1#code/PTAEBUE8AcFMGcDGAnAltALqVA7UBHAVwQ1QHscAoSjGWUAKTN3AEMAjAG1gB5wA+UAF5QAb0qhQGDtwByrALawAXBADcE0MlgZCyHAGEynQgpzxVbLrCMmz8PnQDyAMytzFvAfwDaAXQ0AXw0aOkZmQ2NTcz5BEXBQWAAPDFgcABN4UEIcAGscMgB3KkkAfggZGyj7RzhXd1h5JVj+TVUcWAA3WGQQkAgAC1QsxDJ0+lZOTiKslzJkLR09SLtzRO4lHAwsjDJQdgmcSFBOyeJQMhdQViOpSspk6HmsWjhw3AcE5NSMrIam2BxMSaABWEQsoAAFE4FKgMDwmCxKjwAEqwTisVLpf6eFoAGlAAHJtLp9LZovBCYIAGTAyT0xaklYU1SI5k1NEYrE45refyaQIASn5wUo-XAQxGYwmUxmoDmC1YyGQrGOJOWoFGq3WsE22ykewOFxwnGOpxMCCkA0x120mrICgUFGuTpwAHN4FhJpxQPA4IhUC5UIgpHQspDYAA6N2R42momodKEwVisCPZ6ht5sz6JFJpTIVawAoHifqSMEfVkRBqo9GY2DYyoAlr8-qi1OgACiSUU0G4FyuhXmuVwbszo+olFG5iwyGMCG7ve4AEYq0jrDxifPKSXNAzJNIi55VFvuJS8Xv9+qydVzKofITE4SCYScJ5CX5QP0nABpAkHRBWEIeB6DnM9sCyCh429IoG2wdJrgyYB5lAN8lFjABlAYyEITgEMmeA9iHZBcmwK5dUwSACRQtDDnSZCFkTUBClYLJtCdbp0kvdtp09LRt0XBQ+1gAAmNccBrU8ECpYQ6X3A8m2PIkwOki95Mka92TvUAHyfF84GQWF4HgcgcA-L8wCwnC8PlVhUE4f9YEA4DQO3CC42OGDCjgpibgQ2iCQMoyTOdYZULIL1TnsyoDX4s9uJCXisCC+BBOEgBmcTJKC4YQvMGSRHEdS7iPJQTxy4zTPPS8GU08l7HvR8k30npgtM8zvz-fYnKAkDQAqvKsjCqDPNlbyEN8pCUIG0yEuoJL+ta1KeyE7gABYsuRQkZooHdZKK9TDw8MqiR2-K1PUurbwhXTmqJWiOss7DcIQlw7Ic7rnL6s6hsgk1Rumcb4MQ+jpta3LTIJWj3IKSL3pi3ZFsMiHdrmyd+mSJd6GgOdrAUTFg3Hd0CUKAY0ntBR2FHUdQAUXDSGEzMJmQN1TDSbYp12rBRkp3AG2zcSHCkgB9H6CrkittJ8S8DoZI7GiUqTqvkq7Vhuprn3u98WuRyqKEe0ArJeqF2EILB0jIBAzIwQVbPsxyvux8G9bwMLYeuKKMWsWKVPgbiLskWX6XlgFyudwbnxqxllnqqWNZfB6dba-XP36I2bMhU3zct+Brdtt77c+3r6Ght2Io9+HvcRn7-ZlqOQ8V33I5VpYbzVxq9K1pRNcJQgBgAWjIAYDfT173qhPzQAthBbYA4vwowIZ3V9QhoCeZB9T7weBlrhkg4U0qVGU7dm6vVutPVzvX3fT8LN9Z6bKNX9d-pfeSuOo+ldP2rz9j9WHtvv0eAD8EJPx-C-QO9dFInW2uHKq396SqxZDpeOp04Ep0kGWYB1lQH0GfgyQIAdQCaD8JQdsHYABCrF6CjHGCDKemJWBQz2DjMgeMshk20NQdMG9sBbB6G9RA9AAAijD2DULkm6YwLhhZIHmAgVQQcGgQjfj9RRUdJAoiKOo4qkhEztFMAcXoGj6RnVUJ6NA7oNDFVFMVAAkuYHoGAdG6MTKUdoXQejWN0WY30GBLFum8fJWx6kACq0B0j1hccVNxHjujGN0UjZOOB3F+ICUE-cIT5KcgJrtIY0AboBCjlkxB85RboO0m-TR2i5IxPSOU3Wg0DGUy8SYvR9TfbNKMRkghPT6QOJAhvaJ6lEwNOSRCHAhjWmJNGZ01CUyEnqRKQycJkTUjDPkqMn6qTJktMWXU4WvsdkLL6ZIZZ9IcmkDyegG6bTam6IVLAVAbocA-lgJAUOaDGlVWFi4XIhJTn7i1Mg26YyUb5SKYkvR8AnAdHAGQWFR83qcBAoCn+LgehpCEekS5pkw7fN2gCu5GlYAYu0DgbFf8O5Jkhbowhdyqn7kec8157zPlK1+f8tF9JgUNRQbMk+tKZkwrhQijoqhkWouJYsMlWKGy4ooCeJu3KSWyopQ2Kl-KaXcsCCYoV9JzlzMZVowoGz9z6PmXs7ltFzH+NHIC85kgBlOLNQyWJqFPH7PUjatJ9qTGOtAKsqJ9zNnpB2Z661nhUkWL9TYwFCrzD5MKX0kpITdW6oeEkdeLwwg8noCIXI7zLigFEYeahD4pGcBkXI7QlI-APmUR+EImbs1M0LNwP+fBcw-ALHmuImhC2QGLaWjg5bCSVuraMWtH4G2VDrT4cA9bCQmqbdwrNGZXj0CgHUNw0CvBAi+HmX47aFZKFAOUBIcTWmhDeMohNwCbldu+PmP4e7+2SBHeIkCFbpGyKndJJdjb62LofPepNq6W0brCJchsean1Ht7W+4Qmg711iuYmx9AgfC7KMUu7QarsUJtXUAA))

## Final comments

So far, it only seems possible to have all values from all tables, or only values from all tables that are common amongst all tables. I have been exploring solutions which seemed somewhat similar: [Typescript, merge object types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682569/typescript-merge-object-types/49683575#49683575) but I'm starting to wonder if what I'm attempting is possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include all the relevant code appears as plaintext in the question and not only as a playground link. Right now it lacks definitions for `TableColumns` and `RelatedTableName` and other machinery; it should all be here as plaintext to be a [mre], and you might consider trying to whittle it down to the minimum; ideally it should all fit on one screen.  I mean, there doesn't seem to be much use for `Database` and `"golf_scores"` if you're always drilling down here. I'm sure your goal is achievable but I'd like to see an easier to use [mre] before delving into it.

Comment: Once you do that, my guess is that you need to distribute `joins` over unions in `RelatedTableName<T>`. One way to do that is shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wgGyMw). If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining, but please do [edit] the question first to present a [mre]. If it doesn't meet your needs, what am I missing?

Comment: The solution provided by @jcalz above solved the problem.  It seems obvious now that I look at it 

Thanks again jcalz !

Comment: So shall I write up an answer then?

Comment: Yes please that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in

```
type Joins<T extends TableName> = {
  joins: (Omit<JoinTable<RelatedTableName<T>>, 'returnColumns'> & {
      returnColumns: JoinColumns<RelatedTableName<T>>[]
  })[]
};
```

the type of the `joins` property does not *distribute* over [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `RelatedTableName<T>`.  Let's split that definition into some pieces for ease of discussion.  Your code is equivalent to:

```
type Joins<T extends TableName> = {
  joins: J<RelatedTableName<T>>
}

type J<R> = (Omit<JoinTable<R>, 'returnColumns'> & {
  returnColumns: JoinColumns<R>[]
})[]
```

When `R` is a union type like `R1 | R2 | R3`, you really want `J<R>` to also be a union type like `J<R1> | J<R2> | J<R3>`.  That's what "distribute over unions" means.  But that's not how `J<R>` works.  [The `Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) doesn't distribute over unions, and even if it did, it wouldn't distribute as a single chunk along with `& { returnColumns: JoinColumns<R>[] }`.

---

Luckily it's pretty easy to turn a non-distributive type into a distributive one.  You can either write a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) like

```
type DistribJ<R> = R extends unknown ?
  (Omit<JoinTable<R>, 'returnColumns'> & {
    returnColumns: JoinColumns<R>[]
  })[] : never
```

or, since `R` is expected to be keylike, you can write a *distributive object type* (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) where you [map over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `R` and then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the mapped type:

```
type DistribJ<R extends PropertyKey> = {
  [K in R]: (Omit<JoinTable<R>, 'returnColumns'> & {
    returnColumns: JoinColumns<R>[]
  })[] }[R]
```

If you replace `J` with either `DistribJ` above, your code will start working.

---

To demonstrate, I'll use the distributive object version and dispense with the intermediate `J` type, as follows:

```
type Joins<T extends TableName> = {
  joins: ({ [K in RelatedTableName<T>]: (Omit<JoinTable<K>, 'returnColumns'> & {
    returnColumns: JoinColumns<K>[]
  }) }[RelatedTableName<T>])[]
};
```

And now everything behaves as desired. If we examine `Joins<'role_permissions'>` (expanding the type as described in [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218)), we get:

```
type JoinsRolePermissionsExplicit = 
  ExpandRecursively<Joins<'role_permissions'>>;
/* type JoinsRolePermissionsExplicit = {
    joins: ({
        tableName: "permissions";
        returnColumns: ("id" | "permission")[];
    } | {
        tableName: "roles";
        returnColumns: ("id" | "name")[];
    })[];
} */
```

which is exactly what you want:

```
const combinedJoins: Joins<'role_permissions'> = {
  joins: [
    {
      tableName: 'roles',
      returnColumns: ['id', 'name', 'permission'] // error!
      //~~~~~~~~~~~
      // Type '("id" | "name" | "permission")[]' is not assignable to 
      // type '("id" | "name")[] | ("id" | "permission")[]'.
    },
    {
      tableName: 'permissions',
      returnColumns: ['id', 'name', 'permission'] // error!
      //~~~~~~~~~~~
      // Type '("id" | "name" | "permission")[]' is not assignable to 
      // type '("id" | "name")[] | ("id" | "permission")[]'.(2322)
    },
    {
      tableName: 'roles',
      returnColumns: ['id', 'name', 'uh-oh'] // error!
      //                            ~~~~~~~
      // Type '"uh-oh"' is not assignable to type '"id" | "name" | "permission"'.
    },
    {
      tableName: 'roles',
      returnColumns: ['id', 'name']  // okay
    },
    {
      tableName: 'roles',
      returnColumns: ['name']  // okay
    }
  ]
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#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-0BIPBVEkkKy1itjjgrkauS8rU0tIZTJCyWgZDFUjC43ivL+mRjnhlmhKcVVojlCtwXxqdVgDWysZaKoGQ3VCOyPHF2tRiz1BzWhuxON1VqJuAjXdtjoujudNfqBaUTap7RCIFAAFEkopoNxQGQXKAwemgbgAOaZ6Dn11degALU+1VqC4bzQARMLuAB9UXDeDwchzDfNpKEQChHi0YwEC3HduFeMcJg7eYoPgAcCk0aRrFjVRkO4VCpm2U0+0JOVZlQKJZhRHBPFmal1yccUZnYWBEFYQh4HoT8EGwTIKE4SBQFYThOHBOtsCiQT0mAdNQGopQADpQAAZQACzIQhOAkoT4DII8T2wQ9YAUTBIBmGS5PoVgpJk8ij1YTJtAUMhGSiVdqDA8wsC4+AYOM7hOQQyZcIQNCh0wjwlBw7zKMI3tR1I8jKLmX8HgAihaNAddVPUzTQBcVhUE4JiWLYjjILwnj9xwfjBOE0SJNsqyJIsmYUv-QDKtBLBWHpAramsKRdO8tzQPArBfx87c-NgABmQKkLatKDXQyRwqaSLkqZP8lvw2L0U9VQfDIiiUUWwCMvoxjQGY1j2PoM7wMqviBKEkSwTExrrOQUAHqoYJ3LGn6tsm2DYAAFnm6weFmX7UKLVbXw2mGttSwDdpNOKDoSk65gsi6wGyjSJPywritusrYae6qXrq96Gq0r6geQbbAJmCzOrIbresK7JBqZlnwJGt1NySaAmuqRA9AAxl+JaT4fV+fl93YIoWKwUNy3lRVQCBKUDwgZstzF9IJal1AZcgPh5T8QRAhpdQWW6bNKiggUUfa8Cjc4VBEBGT4jfFlizYtjU4mhrif3dna1n4DRgAAKkvd1SngF3uDd5nUc90Xvd9rAVpxEsygGY0cQRrDPFUN9YbfDQy7Lkcsf6N9yLfUAAB9QGrqPALfKk65xO3O9Lsu1uwrvvNrzR660Ij4ub1uO67iy+-8Ae7X79pQHj4BqHXZJQZ+4VrAUOofcvc8ZjBFS0lAMCFHYc9z1ABQNNIXd6FvQTkDPUw0gweAo1PJ3zIA-XAdZswIQcMFSOmcPbLSHEXQ4Php5DlHojFQOoUIxRno3c0h1jpJVmHjU6Pd0p0TAEyYUyAACEqDJAgAAH7MJYawxh9DMpgCgN0WYC8oht07m+FeS9u5wKWqvPwswObdXameaiA0MC6Q4euL+vCW78JESvKkS8+ECK7r9CRsx5KoMCARMuI8pAYJwrDHB9c8EHAIYlKiNFSFiPOhQxIyBqF0JnkwthbDlFcLCGoxegjhGCIMVSKRDxZKc0ErI+Re5FGgECUnOYujNGeAkTo9RejRECxwIY+S-ROQzU5JyC4JizE4gsWPSuWC8K2IbnPLGR0nG4xcXMQgKkAC0ZAVL408d41JM9RljJnv49hvigk8LfN0vpKk3zRMyF1eJAE5G82Sao3JmSlB5IMUYqpqDalWIaSFapzTMb4OxkQvG1JOH7iBKwSARzzEcLqUjaKFzhwtOuUdO5DCwBkCeS8supjjnvNOcjNx4Emk-KuQ4m5riCkZQecC55rzQDkn+nvMAkQypgSiJZdIoAoh1FYGzXS0Bj7cAUJkG+2hqCpnTFgXAqRkD5UQPQW45L2D2XoLKM8xgXBfiQOmBAqhS6NEOBY2GkqOGSBdmCeV4zxK0lMMxZA69Rm-VUOyc82qwWGpxAASXMEyDAKrxnkUhImRkWqFU4l1aAfVOAzzGrtB60AABVaAZLUhWrGTau1yZHWSF+ral1TwDWOv+mMp8Z9wIqXQMggIHC412KgrAgpMrHVKsDaM8i2as7FxwBq0Nqqi3eXVQ-CtoyM0zzNRxMUBaZ5FrlbJctDrK1RC-NWzttbu31q9b6-1mCLFl3bWQ8wkay2Dq9ZIKtKFZ1dq9Q2+uCbSBJpTYdMNaDxkuHFagORkpIDj2hTmr8LggSzAXTiMCfzjrFvgahNNqrF3wCcHScAZAv2YPypwDid6TQuCZGkLlURN2AWsdO1CwHZ6ge0DgCD8U2kUTfeM8FqqJ310PdoY9OBT3nu8lem98GH2IrQ327BGHK2fu-b+ukqgANAb3SBsDyG6xQYoFFbB8HtCIfA3WVDhDaP1sdWJz1HD+04fzfuttUQa2arvRZPV0a3Vrq9U2i1rb67BtkkmIdYzVNRrQBp2NI6-W1l05OqIs7DMqc8JG117qLN5vnGjZN0BU3GvXRmjoHRKDMozF-Rc9ARC60gPrHlmF+VHSFZwEVYrtCvqOtK2iIQguixZWkxoEYFZ+nzBg-ImhIvRd5XF2YCWktgRS7RNL2RUvgD8EdJVGWmXZZC2EbhsBowYLliIAreYwwRXoKGBIIaHXC2ldx8wXmcy+mG2FkrkgYscEq9V0VtWQotdmOllrzXWsee3d59rWW0xde6JuusYW+C5iVst4QmgZvHbmymloPg52at2wJjjEHZvtaAA)

Comment: Thank you for your hard work @jcalz! It is very much appreciated =)